# Aside from the first win, are there any rewards to playing Tavern Brawl?

Tags: hearthstone

Achievements, more packs, or anything?

Comment: I currently have a daily quest for 5 Tavern Brawl wins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it gets the same treatment as casual mode in regards to rewards. As in it counts towards daily quests and you get the usual 10 gold per 3 wins.

Comment: As of the latest patch, there is also a daily quest to win Brawls. (5, I believe.)

Comment: I like to use Tavern Brawls after my first win in order to complete class specific quests if i don't have that deck (Win 2 games with Warrior and don't have a Warrior deck? Brawl!)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Currently there are no rewards beyond the first win.

I speculate that in the future there might be rewards for more wins or alternatively you will have to win multiple times to get the reward.